# django-filter for django rest framework: in operator doesn't work correctly (it thinks it's a choice field?)

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filters

Let's say we have Pizza and Topping models and Topping has Foreign Key field to Pizza.

We have a django rest framework viewset that returns toppings.

We want to be able to ask question for toppings which are used in pizzas with given IDs, like this:

```
GET /toppings?pizza_id__in=1,2,456
```

We have

```
class ToppingsFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        strict = False
        fields = {
            'id': ['exact'],
            'pizza_id': ['exact', 'in']
        }
```

The problem is when calling the GET with a non-existing pizza_id, I'm getting the following error:

```
{
    "pizza_id__in": [
        "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."
    ]
}
```

If passing valid pizza IDs (existing ones) it works as expected!

Is this default behaviour? It doesn't seem to make any sense. Why is it even doing those kind of validations on a GET operation. The intention of the GET /toppings?pizza_id__in=1,2,435456 is clearly selecting the following objects:

```
SELECT from toppings where pizza_id IN (1,2,435456)
```

Comment: Any reason why you would want to use a non-existing id in the filter? typically the list is loaded in the front and the user picks from the list. The validation is probably to warn developers when they are doing the wrong thing

Comment: Thay call to API does not need to originate from UI, it can be some testing, or some other integration. An underlaying SELECT statement is valid, so why should the API return HTTP 400 by default as if something bad happened?

Comment: That is one of the extra functions of the API as it doesn't just give you access to the DB so you shouldn't expect that it will repeat exactly the same thing the DB does. It's just a validation stage. You can override the behaviour if it doesn't go with your logic.